# Render component before and after login

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I build app like Fb with react, redux (handle Jwt,...) and react router v4. I want my component like the picture

Before login: !https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nFgfeQQpjCzFtMIXsOlhhJSkxvgJ6NUp/view?usp=sharing!

After login: !https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C_tTr29zeyRqWRHwzBo6Pt0YTIsaf-3k/view?usp=sharing!

But I still want use private route for page like fb.com/setting (redirect Login page if user not login)

Give me keyword or idea pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest solution would be to have Page with conditional rendering:

```
HomePage = (props) => (props.isLoggedIn
  ? <NotAuthenticatedPage {...props}/>
  : <AuthenticatedPage  {...props}/>
)
```